# Magento 2: Product repository's getList() method doesn't retrieve recent items

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, magento-catalog

I have a model where I look for products from the database, filtered by a custom attribute:

```
/**
 * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $_productRepository;

/**
 * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
 */
protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;

public function __construct
(
    Context $context,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
)
{
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface[]
 */
public function getPartnerOffers()
{
    $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder
        ->addFilter('is_for_partners', 1)
        ->create();

    var_dump( $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems() );
    die;
}
```

When I execute getPartnerOffers(), it returns zero items. But when I edit the ProductRepository class to print the SQL query, then execute that query in a mysql console, I get all my items just fine.

I have two leads until there, but don't know how to investigate further:

1. The product repository might not search directly into the database but into some cache that I don't know of. It seems unlikely as I can find these items when I look for them directly using:

   ```
   $this->_productRepository->get('product-sku');
   ```
2. These products that I look for have been created programmaticaly in the InstallData script. Maybe they're not "valid" enough to be returned, even though they exist in the catalog_product_entity table?

I'm starting to get really lost here, I had no trouble creating my own table, model and repository for another module, but working with a core repository really seems harder.